# How do I display the matching duplicate records next to a single record in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to left join a data source to create two tables that match on Account ID. Then I need to display the duplicate match next to a single row if it meets certain criteria (having same first 12 characters in Name, same ZIP, same City). For instance, a duplicate record would be one that has the same ZIP, City, and first 12 letters of the Name but a different Account ID.

Here is an example of what that would look like:

[image]

I created 2 instances of the same table and joined them and it gave me what I wanted except it stacked the duplicates on top of one another instead of displaying them next to one another.

Here is an example of what I previously attempted:

```
SELECT TableName1.[Account ID], TableName1.[Account Name], TableName1.[ZIP], TableName1.[City]
  FROM [DataSource] TableName1
  JOIN (SELECT LEFT([Account Name],12) AS [TN2 Account Name], [ZIP] AS [TN2 ZIP], Count(*) AS [Count], [City] AS [TN 2 City]
          FROM [DataSource]
         GROUP BY [Account Name], [ZIP], [City]
        HAVING COUNT(*) >1) TableName2 ON LEFT(TableName1.[Account Name],12) = LEFT(TableName2.[TN2 Account Name],12)
                                      AND TableName1.[ZIP] = TableName2.[ZIP]
                                      AND TableName1.[City] = TableName2.[City] 
ORDER BY TableName1.[Account Name], TableName1.[ZIP], TableName1.[City]
```

It gave me a result like the following:

[image]

Any advice on how I could get duplicate records to show up next to just one match of the Account ID like the first image? First time posting sorry if not enough information.

Comment: can ypu provide some dumy data for table 1 and table 2

Comment: Please, do not post images of data, they are not useful. You may post your data as insert statements or at least as a plain text. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557)

Comment: How do you decide which is the main one and which is the duplicate?

Comment: I removed the `mysql` tag, as your code is clearly for SQL Server

Comment: +1 for @Charlieface's question. If accounts A, B and C are all duplicates, how do we know which appears on the left? Should they each appear on the left in turn? Each duplicate pair then appears twice, once in each "direction". Even if you restrict each duplication to appear only once by requiring the record on the left to have a lower `Account ID` than the one on the right, you'll still have cases like A matching B and C, but B also matching C. It would be natural to only have the one with the lowest `Account ID` on the left, but that's not the approach you've taken in the data you supply.

Answer (score 1):

The code below takes a particular approach to the questions in my comment.

First, it assumes that all duplicates should be shown once. If there are three in a set of duplicates (A, B and C), each pair appears. There is a pair with A and B, a pair with A and C and a pair with B and C. You may not want that. Second, in any pair of duplicates, we always put on the left the account with the lower `Account ID`. Again, you may not want that.

```
SELECT
    ds1.[Account ID],
    ds1.[Account Name],
    ds1.ZIP,
    ds1.City,
    ds2.[Account ID] as [Account ID 2],
    ds2.[Account Name] as [Account Name 2],
    ds2.ZIP as [ZIP 2],
    ds2.City as [City 2]
FROM
    [DataSource] ds1
JOIN [DataSource] ds2 ON
    ds1.ZIP = ds2.ZIP
    AND ds1.City = ds2.City
    AND LEFT(ds1.[Account Name],12) = LEFT(ds2.[Account Name],12)
    AND ds1.[Account ID] < ds2.[Account ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

as I can see so far try to do left join on the first table, again without dummy data is hard to give you an answer

```
SELECT TableName1.[Account ID], TableName1.[Account Name], TableName1.[ZIP], TableName1.[City]
  FROM [DataSource] TableName1
  left JOIN (SELECT LEFT([Account Name],12) AS [TN2 Account Name], [ZIP] AS [TN2 ZIP], Count(*) AS [Count], [City] AS [TN 2 City]
          FROM [DataSource]
         GROUP BY [Account Name], [ZIP], [City]
        HAVING COUNT(*) >1) TableName2 
                                       ON LEFT(TableName1.[Account Name],12) = LEFT(TableName2.[TN2 Account Name],12)
                                      AND TableName1.[ZIP] = TableName2.[ZIP]
                                      AND TableName1.[City] = TableName2.[City] 
ORDER BY TableName1.[Account Name], TableName1.[ZIP], TableName1.[City]
```